# codepen errors with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, codepen

I get an error in my codepen 
ReferenceError: require is not defined
I have imported intersection-observer from react-intersection-observer@5.0.5/dist/react-intersection-observer.cjs.js
:
[codepen link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bKqvNM?editors=1111)

```
 class AdImpression extends React.Component {
  state = {
    tracked: '',
  };

  handleChange = event => {
    if (event.isIntersecting && event.intersectionRatio >= 0.5) {
      this.recordedTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ tracked: 'ad--tracked' });
      }, 1000);
      return;
    }
    clearTimeout(this.recordedTimeout);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Observer onChange={this.handleChange} threshold={0.5}>
        <div className={`ad ${this.state.tracked}`} />
      </Observer>
    );
  }
}

class ImpressionTracking extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <div>
        <div className="header visible">Criteria: 50% visible pixels + 1 continuous sec</div>
        <div className="body body--center">
            <AdImpression index={1} />
            <AdImpression index={2} />
            <AdImpression index={3} />
        </div>
    </div>
   );
  }
}
```

Comment: I've had some issues with Codepen and React. The only way that has ever worked for me is to copy the code from a React-pen that works, and keep working on that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the *umd* version of this package. In the filename, *cjs* stands for *common js* which needs a `require` function in the global scope. *umd* will try to guess what's available while * esm* is for es6 module and you need to use the "add a module" feature of codepen.

Answer (score 0):

this error comes from your included [react-intersection-observer file](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@researchgate/react-intersection-observer@0.7.3/lib/js/index.min.js)